# ipa file contains illegal characters?

Tags: swift, ipa, mdm, airwatch

I am trying to upload an ipa file (written in Swift) to our MDM console (AirWatch). The console is .Net, and when I try to upload I get a message saying the path contains illegal characters. The path does not, and I can upload other ipa files to MDM, so I'm left with something wrong with the ipa itself. The MDM software reads the IPA when it's uploading it to determine version and other information. Anyone got any ideas?

-MJC

Comment: maybe it's not the ipa itself, but one of the files it contains might... try unzipping the ipa and look through its contents

Comment: I've been looking through it and I don't see anything obvious so far.

Comment: Is this the first iOS internal application you tried to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that one of the folders embedded in the .ipa file has the 'cross' character (hex=10, ascii=16, DLE) in the 'LaunchScreen.storyboardc' folder.
This can be seen by opening the .ipa file using 7zip in Windows.
When we remove this folder using 7zip, Airwatch accepts the ipa file.